# Python: Better way to compare two elements within two nested dict / list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there better way to compare two nested dict / list without using nested for loops. I'm trying to match the serial number of the devices from two different sources, and create a dictionary output to combine two data. Having two for loops works for me but I feel like there is a better way of doing this. In reality, list_one has 15000 records, list_two has 8000 records. I'm pretty sure, each record from list_one is looping through 8000 records in list_two to find the match so basically, it's checking 120,000,000 possibilities with the if statement.

```
list_one = [{'sn': '1234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}, {'sn': '2234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}, {'sn': '3234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}]

list_two = [['1234', 'user_a', '8/22/2022'], ['2234', 'user_b', '8/22/2022'], ['3234', 'user_c', '8/22/2022']]

result_list = []
for l in list_one:
  for t in list_two:
    if l['sn'] == t[0]:
      result = {'sn': l['sn'], 'user': t[1], 'check_in': l['last_checkin']}
      result_list.append(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```py
list_one = [{'sn': '1234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}, {'sn': '2234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}, {'sn': '3234', 'model': 'Dell', 'last_checkin': '8/22/2022'}]

list_two = [['1234', 'user_a', '8/22/2022'], ['2234', 'user_b', '8/22/2022'], ['3234', 'user_c', '8/22/2022']]

lam = lambda l1: None if len(x:= [{"sn": l1["sn"], "user": l2[1], "check_in": l1["last_checkin"]} for l2 in list_two if l2[0] == l1['sn']]) == 0 else x
result_list = map(lam, list_one)
print(*result_list)
```

I don't know if this works for you, but you can try something similar.

Comment: basicly i created a lambda function which returns the dict formated if the sn code from l1 matches with the sn code from l2, otherwise it returns None, the map function applies the lambda function for each element from list_one and finaly it prints the result_list generator